# How to Pass Props to Modal Component in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I need to pass Flatlist data to modal in react native. Like, on click the item from the flatlist, it shows the modal with data for selected item.  Here is my code below

**Home.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, Image, TouchableOpacity, Alert, Button } from 'react-native';
import { Popup } from './Modal';
import * as productdata from '../data/productdata.js';

export default class Home extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isLoading: true,
            dataSource: [],
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({
            isLoading: false,
            dataSource: productdata.product,
        })
    }

    popupRef = React.createRef()
    onShowPopup = item => {   
       popupRef.show();  
    }
    onClosePopup = () => {
        popupRef.close()
    }


    ProductList = ({ item }) => (
        <View style={styles.listItem}>

            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.onShowPopup(item)} style={{ height: 100, width: 100, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center" }}>
                <Image source={item.photo} style={{ width: 100, height: 100, borderRadius: 15 }} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <View style={{ alignItems: "center", flex: 1, marginTop: 20 }}>
                <Text style={{ fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: 22 }}>{item.name}</Text>
                <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, fontWeight: "bold" }}>{item.price}</Text>
            </View>
            <Popup name="Product Details" ref={(target) => popupRef = target} onTouchOutside={this.onClosePopup} />

        </View>
    );

    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>

                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.dataSource}
                    renderItem={this.ProductList}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.name}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

**Modal.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Modal, Dimensions, TouchableWithoutFeedback, StyleSheet, View, Text, Button, Image, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';

const deviceHeight = Dimensions.get("window").height
export class Popup extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            show: false,   
        }
    }

    show = () => {
        this.setState({ show: true })
    }
    close = () => {
        this.setState({ show: false })
    }

    
    renderOutsideTouchable(onTouch) {
        const view = <View style={{ flex: 1, width: '100%' }} />
        if (!onTouch) return view

        return (
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={onTouch} style={{ flex: 1, width: '100%' }}>
                {view}
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
        )
    }

    renderTitle = () => {
        const { name } = this.props
        return (
            <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
                <Text style={{
                    color: 'black', fontSize: 20,
                    fontWeight: 'bold', margin: 15
                }}>
                    {name}
                </Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
    renderContent = (item) => {
        return (
            <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', marginBottom: 10 }}>
           <View style={styles.card}>
  <Text style={{ fontSize: 20, fontWeight: '500', fontWeight: 'bold', alignSelf: 'center', margin: 5 }}/>
                   
                    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                        <Text style={styles.button}>Add to Cart</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </View>
        )
    }

    render() {
        let { show } = this.state
        const { onTouchOutside, title } = this.props
        return (
         <Modal  animationType={'slide'} transparent={true} visible={show} onRequestClose={this.close}>
          <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: '#000000AA', justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}>
                    {this.renderOutsideTouchable(onTouchOutside)}
           <View style={{
                        backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF', width: '100%', height: '70%', borderTopRightRadius:20, borderTopLeftRadius: 20, paddingHorizontal: 20, maxHeight: deviceHeight * 5}}>

                        {this.renderTitle()}
                        {this.renderContent()}

                    </View>
                </View>
            </Modal>
        )
    }
}
```

**My Problem:** I am not able to pass the flatlist item data to a Modal component and have no better idea solving it in this code.

Please help me and if any including, changes or complete solution for perfect understanding for the requirement would be really great. Many Thanks in Advance!

Comment: (1) After creating the `popupRef` ref you should reference it as `this.popupRef`, (2) to get the current value of the ref use `this.popupRef.current`, (3) You are mixing legacy and current ref syntax, when attaching the ref use `ref={this.popupRef}`, (4) you have only a single ref but many data elements and `Popup`s, use only a single `Popup` component, (5) the `onPress` handler has the item you want displayed, you could save that in state and set `show` true, then consume the item saved in state in the modal.

Comment: If you still struggle, then I can try creating a working expo snack if you provide some sample `productdata` to use as data for the list.

Comment: Sir, I tried till 3rd point of your suggestions. But am still stuck in finding the problem. Absolutely, I created a sandbox where you can find **productdata.js** file. Please find the link below, Thank you Sir

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/dhruvareact-native-modal-nfjvp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to duplicate open state in modal/popup. Simply set the style and open. Assume open close state is controlled by parent component, so if rendering modal/popup it is open by definition.

```
class Popup extends React.Component {
  renderOutsideTouchable(onTouch) {
    const view = <View style={{ flex: 1, width: '100%' }} />;
    if (!onTouch) return view;

    return (
      <TouchableWithoutFeedback
        onPress={onTouch}
        style={{ flex: 1, width: '100%' }}>
        {view}
      </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
    );
  }

  renderTitle = () => {
    const { name } = this.props;
    return (
      <View style={{ alignItems: 'center' }}>
        <Text
          style={{
            color: 'black',
            fontSize: 20,
            fontWeight: 'bold',
            margin: 15,
          }}>
          {name}
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  };

  renderContent = () => {
    const { item } = this.props;
    return (
      <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', marginBottom: 10 }}>
        <View style={styles.card}>
          <Text
            style={{
              fontSize: 20,
              fontWeight: '500',
              // fontWeight: "bold",
              alignSelf: 'center',
              margin: 5,
            }}
          />

          <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <Text>Name: {item.name}</Text>
            <Text>Price: {item.price}</Text>
            <Text>Description: {item.desc}</Text>
            <Text>Rating: {item.rating}</Text>
            <Text style={styles.button}>Add to Cart</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  };

  render() {
    const { onTouchOutside, title } = this.props;
    return (
      <Modal
        animationType={'slide'}
        transparent
        visible // <-- visible prop is truthy
        onRequestClose={this.close}>
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            backgroundColor: '#000000AA',
            justifyContent: 'flex-end',
            zIndex: 1000,
          }}>
          {this.renderOutsideTouchable(onTouchOutside)}
          <View
            style={{
              backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF',
              width: '100%',
              height: '70%',
              borderTopRightRadius: 20,
              borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
              paddingHorizontal: 20,
              maxHeight: deviceHeight * 5,
            }}>
            {this.renderTitle()}
            {this.renderContent()}
          </View>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    );
  }
}
```

A react ref isn't necessary for opening a modal/popup to display a specific item. Change the `onShowPopup` and `onClosePopup` to set/nullify a clicked on item. Conditionally render the `Popup` outside the `Flatlist`.

```
class Home extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      dataSource: productdata.product,
      isLoading: false,
      popupItem: null,
    };
  }

  onShowPopup = (popupItem) => {
    this.setState({ popupItem });
  };

  onClosePopup = () => {
    this.setState({ popupItem: null });
  };

  ProductList = ({ item }) => (
    <View style={styles.listItem}>
      <TouchableOpacity
        onPress={() => this.onShowPopup(item)}
        style={{
          height: 100,
          width: 100,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}>
        <Image
          source={item.photo}
          style={{ width: 100, height: 100, borderRadius: 15 }}
        />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View style={{ alignItems: 'center', flex: 1, marginTop: 20 }}>
        <Text style={{ fontWeight: 'bold', fontSize: 22 }}>{item.name}</Text>
        <Text style={{ fontSize: 18, fontWeight: 'bold' }}>{item.price}</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.state.popupItem && (
          <Popup
            name="Product Details"
            item={this.state.popupItem} // <-- pass pop item
            onTouchOutside={this.onClosePopup}
          />
        )}
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          renderItem={this.ProductList}
          keyExtractor={(item) => item.name}
        />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

[Expo Snack](https://snack.expo.io/@drew.w.reese/mature-popsicle)

Comment: Found mistakes in my code and cleared it with your help. Thank you so much for taking your time and clear explanation, Sir. It is working good now as expected.